# How to fix update statement blocking multiple tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, c

I have ran into an issue when using a mysql database where, after creating a new table and adding CRUD database query logic to my web application (with backend written in c), update querys will sometimes take 10-20 minute to execute.

The web application has apache modules that talk to server daemons that have a connection to a mysql (MariaDB 10.4) database. The server daemons each have about 20 work threads, waiting to handle any requests from the apache modules. The work threads maintain a consent connection to the mysql database. I added a new table of the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
( 
   table_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   index_id INT NOT NULL,
   int_column_1 INT DEFAULT 0,
   decimal_column_1 DECIMAL(9,3) DEFAULT 0,
   decimal_column_2 DECIMAL(9,3) DEFAULT 0,
   varchar_column_1 varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
   varchar_column_2 varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
   deleted tinyint DEFAULT 0,
   PRIMARY KEY (table_id) ,
   KEY index_on_index_id (index_id)
)
```

Then I added the following crud operations:
1. RETRIEVE:
 `SELECT * FROM MyTable table_id, varchar_column_1,... WHERE index_id = ${given index_id}`
2. CREATE:
`INSERT INTO MyTable (index_id, varchar_column_2, ,,,) VALUES ( ${given}, ${given})`
Note: This is done using a prepare statement because ${given varchar_column_2} is a user entered value.
3. UPDATE:
`` UPDATE MyTable SET varchar_column_1 = ISNULL(${given varchar_column_2}, `varchar_column_2 `) WHERE table_id = ${given table_id} `` 
Note: This is also done using a prepare statement because ${given varchar_column_2} is a user entered value. Also, the isnull is a kludge solution to the possibility that the given varchar_column_2 might be null, so that the column will just be set to the value in the table. 
4. DELETE:
`UPDATE MyTable SET deleted = 1 WHERE table_id = ${given table_id}`

Finally, there is a delete index_id operation:
`UPDATE MyTable SET deleted = 1 WHERE index_id = ${given index_id }`

This was deployed to a production server without proper testing. On that production server, a script I wrote was ran that filled MyTable with about 30,000 entries. Then, using the crud operations, about 600 updates, 50 creates, 20 deletes, and thousands of retrieves were performed on the table. The problem that is occurring is that after some time (an hour or two) of these operations being performed, the update operation would take 10+ minutes to execute. Eventually, all of the work threads in the server daemon would be stuck waiting on the update operations, and any other requests to the daemon would time out. This behavior happened twice in one day and one more time two days later.

There were three parts of this behavior that really confused me. One is that all update operations on the database were being blocked. So even if the daemon, or any daemon, was updating a different table in database, that update would take 10+ minutes. The next is that the select operations would execute instantly as all the update queries were taking 10+ minutes. Finally, after 10-20 minutes, all of the 20-ish update queries would successfully execute, the database would be correctly updated, and the threads would go back to working properly.

I received a dump of the database and ran 
`EXPLAIN ${mysql query}`
 for each of the new CRUD queries, and none produced strange results. In the "Extras" column, the only entry was "using where clause" for the queries that have where clauses. Another potential problem is the use of varchars. Since the UPDATE operations are used the most and are the ones that seem to be causing the problem, I thought maybe the fact that the varchars are changing sizes a lot (they range from 8 chars to 500 chars), it might run into some mysql memory issues that cause the long execution time. I also thought maybe there was an issue with table level locks, but running 
 
`Show status like ' table%` 
returned table_locks_waited = 0.

Unfortunately, no database monitoring was being done on the production server that was having issues, I only have the order of the transactions as they happened. To this, each time this issue occurred, the first update query that was blocked was an update to a different table in the database. It was the same query twice (but it is also the most common update query in the application), but it has been in the application for months without any issues.

I tried to reproduce this issue on a server with the same table and CRUD operations, but with only 600 entries in MyTable. Making about 100 update requests, 20 create requests, 5 delete requests, and hundreds of get requests. I could not reproduce the issue of the update queries taking 10+ minutes. This makes me think that maybe the size of the table has something to do with it.

I am looking for any suggestions on what might be causing this issue, or any ideas on how to better diagnose the problem.

Sorry for the extremely long question. I am a junior software engineer that is in a little over his head. Any help would be really appreciated. I can also provide any additional information about the database or application if needed.

Comment: This sounds like it a transaction issue (e.g. the updates may wait for a lock to be released). This is less dependent on your specific queries, but on what else is going on in your database (e.g. by other users) and/or the flow of your application code. This also makes it harder to reproduce on your test setup, and for us to debug this for you. I'd start by checking if you are actually using transactions in your app and check for locks while the updates wait. Also: if you suspect table size, why not just run your script on the test server (or use the dump you received to have the same data)?

Comment: The output of `show full processlist` while the queries are hanging could yield interesting information.

Comment: @Solarflare, I ran the query: <br><br>
```SHOW STATUS LIKE``` 'Table%';<br><br>
And got the results: <br><br>
Table_locks_immediate  = 101944 |
| Table_locks_waited         | 0      |
| Table_open_cache_hits      | 0      |
| Table_open_cache_misses    | 0      |
| Table_open_cache_overflows | 0      

Does this not mean that the transaction based locks all resolved without waiting?

Comment: No, it means you have no table locks. Since you are probably using innodb, that is expected, as innodb is using row locks. See e.g. [InnoDB Transaction and Locking Information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-information-schema-examples.html), ctx's proposal of `show full processlist` or similar resources. We are currently only guessing though, since we do not know anything about your code or your setup to narrow it down (e.g. if you are actually using transactions). Locks are just the most likely cause of your problem.

Comment: @Solarflare Ahh, I see. Thank you. I misunderstood the results of SHOW STATUS. I am using transactions for certain operations, but no new ones were added with this code change. I will look into the existing transactions in the applications. Thanks again